# "Cylindrical" symmetric ansatz in Yang-Mills theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, symmetry, gauge-invariance, yang-mills

In the E. Witten's [paper](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.38.121) he considers the ansatz for possible solution which would have "cylindrical" symmetry in 4D space-time. It means that this solution coordinate should be invariant under three-dimensional spatial rotations combined with $SU(2)$ gauge transformations. So, he claims that the most general ansatz for $SU(2)$ Yang-Mills potential which possess cylindrical symmetry is the following:

$$A_j ^a = \frac{(\varphi_2 + 1)}{r^2} \epsilon_{j a k} x_k + \frac{\varphi_1}{r^3} \left( \delta_{j a} r^2 - x_j x_a \right) + A_1 \frac{x_j x_a}{r^2} \\
A_0 ^a = \frac{A_0 x^a}{r} $$
All functions here ($\varphi_1, \varphi_2, A_1, A_0$) depend only on three-dimensional spatial radial coordinate $r$ and time $t$.

I would like to check myself if I am right or not. 
Let us consider each part of this ansatz.

The first part: 
$$\epsilon_{j a k} x_k $$
it is invariant because under spatial transformations vector $x_k$ transforms as

$$x_k \to O_{kl} x_l $$
whereas tensor $\epsilon_{jak}$ as
$$\epsilon_{jak} \to O_{jh} O^T _{km} \epsilon_{ham}$$
Here $O^T$ comes from the fact that indeed we have the contraction of tensors $\epsilon_{jak} x_k$ so actually one index (namely, $k$) should be upper index which transforms under $O^T$.

So, we see that two of transformations $O$ and $O^T$ "kill" each other, and one transformation matrix $O$ remains. Then it can be eliminated with appropriate gauge transformation with upper index $a$ which transforms with $O^T$.

The same holds for another parts of the ansatz $\delta_{ja}, x_j x_a$.

Am I right?

And am I right that because of the map $SU(2) \to S^3$ (where $S^3$ is the spatial sphere, base space) we should "mix" spatial and group indices in the ansatz in order to obtain "cylindrical" symmetry?

Thanks.